# Implementing auditing using Autofac if it support method interception?

Tags: .net, ioc-container, audit, autofac

I'm planning to use Autofac IoC for my project where I must implement auditing (Who, What is doing in application). I was already read a lot of articles on this subject (auditing).
My intention was to use method interception to implement this functionality. 
I know that Unity support this, but I was wondering if I can use Autofac for this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

AutoFac has interception capabilities, which rely on Castle DynamicProxy library (same that Castle Windsor uses). Check [this website](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DynamicProxy2) for examples of usage.

Comment: Thanks, I read it.
I decide to go with PostSharp 2.0 for the following reasons:
 - easy to implement,
 - can use declarative programming and have a clear code
   (making attribute for auditing is meter of min)
 - less maintenance need it.

Comment: @ITGoran it was oldies question but Im worndering that could you use Autofac property injecton for postsharp attribute classes?